# Pandas: Convert date from pandas.tslib.Timestamp to pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dates which is in a different type. I want to compare two dates.

```
qcurrent= pd.Series(query.index[-1])
qcurrent= pd.to_datetime(qcurrent, format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.date 

>>> qcurrent
0    2020-05-08
dtype: object
>>>type(current)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

qcsvdate = query1.index[-1][:10]datetime.strptime(query1.index[-1], "%Y-%m-%d")
>>> qcsvdate
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 8, 0, 0)
>>> type(qcsvdate)
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>

if qcurrent.iat[-1]>=qcsvdate[-1]:
    print " today is a Friday"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Timestamp' object does not support indexing
```

How to make both dates can be compare with if condition?

Answer (score 0):

Add `pd.Series` for qcsvdate to standardize both formats

```
qcsvdate= pd.Series(query1.index[-1])
qcsvdate = query1.index[-1][:10]datetime.strptime(query1.index[-1], "%Y-%m-%d")
>>>type(qcsvdate)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```